# Get a review link with Google My Business API

Tags: google-my-business-api

Is there a way to get the link of a review using the GMB APIs?

The closest to what I need is this:

- https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/113400145807499011881/place/ChIJSRSm38NhLxMRBgg2EGMZqKc/

Where the first ID (113400145807499011881) is the ID of the user who left the review, and the second ID (ChIJSRSm38NhLxMRBgg2EGMZqKc) is the place ID.

However, the [review object returned by the API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews#Review) does not seem to contain enough information to obtain the reviewer user ID.

Thank you,
Guido

Answer (score 1):

newReviewUrl is the Parameter if someone read this:
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations#urlattributevalue

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please try to improve your answer by adding context. Have a look at the details from the link> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the *newReviewUrl* field is the *link to the page on Google Search where a customer can leave a review for the location* which is different from what I needed (the link to a specific review).

Comment: This helped me, however, it appears that the ability to get the location has been deprecated.

The newReviewUrl link is in the meta data here: https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/accountid/locations?read_mask=name,metadata

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for a way to get the url to the review overview for a specific location via the API too.
After checking the links, IDs ect. in the API Responses and lots of documentations an tuturials i found NO way to get the link over tha API.

BUT a workarround with a few manual steps can help to find the link (I know that is not a final answer to the question, but maybe it is still helpfull)

- go to google search, and search for you Location/ Company that contains the reviews
- on the right side you should see a pannel that shows the current stars for your location and a link "xxxx Google-Rezensionen"
- klick on this link and copy the url in the browser
  (optional remove parameters like "&client" ect.

Check this [youtube-video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCoGwmrw07E) of the [Step by Step Tuturial](https://gatherup.com/blog/google-review-url-your-business/) to see a tuturial how you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

**Get a review** link looks generally like this `https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid={placeId}`

Here is an example link that we can generate (BTW this is also included in the above-mentioned Google API)

https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=ChIJbYAn0g2lwoARg9MJ0E_QJNo

**Here is an example of where you can get your placeId within the Google business API.**

We have an endpoint in the Google Business API that lists all your businesses. That contains `placeId` in it's response. It is the `https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/{account}/locations?readMask={readMask}`

An example readMask is `name,title,storeCode,regularHours,languageCode,phoneNumbers,categories,storefrontAddress,websiteUri,regularHours,specialHours,serviceArea,labels,adWordsLocationExtensions,latlng,openInfo,metadata,profile,relationshipData,moreHours`

Using this endpoint we can get `placeId` from our reponse